# Speed up my VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

This Macro works however it is very slow is there anywhere I can speed up the macro? I need it to seach at least 1,000 lines because of the amount of data coming in. Not going to have 1,000 lines of data every time but will sometimes.

```
`Sub Issues_Formatting2()
' Issues_Formatting Macro
'

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Cells.UnMerge
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Issues Report"
    With Worksheets("Issues Report").Cells.Font
        .Name = "Trebuchet MS"
        .Size = 10
    End With

    Range("A1:A4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
        "R:\Marketing\Logos\Wolters Kluwer Health\rgb-files\WKH-«_health-logo-185-rgb-.jpg" _
        ).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.5125, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.525, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

    Columns("A:A").Select
    On Error GoTo Rows
    Cells.Find(What:="Implementation Issue: Issue #", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("A7:A" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete

Rows:

  Rows("7:7").RowHeight = 30.75
    Range("A7:Q7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Issue #"
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Title"
    Range("E7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Responsible Party"
    Range("J7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comments"
    Range("M7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "City"
    Range("N7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "State"
    Range("P7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Owner Name"
    Range("Q7").Select
    Columns("Q:Q").ColumnWidth = 23.57
    Range("J7").Select
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 8.43
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 8.86
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 7.43
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 7.43
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 11.86
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 11.57
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 8.6
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 12.2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 20.43
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Rows("7:7").RowHeight = 25.5
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:= _
        "Implementation Record Type", TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("I17").Select
    Range("A8:Q8").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9

    Range("J8:J1000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Dim g As Long
    For g = 7 To 1000
    Cells.Find(What:=":", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Resize(1, 17).Select
        With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With

    Next

    Dim p As Long
    For p = 7 To 1000
    Cells.Find(What:="Grand", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Resize(1, 17).Select
        With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With

    Next

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J7:J1000")

    For Each Cell In rng
        Cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-9], Sheet1!C[-9]:C, 10, FALSE), """")"
    Next Cell

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 7 To 1000
    Cells.Find(What:="Implementation Record Type:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
            ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 23
    Next

    Columns("A:A").Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Cells.Find(What:="Grand Totals", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 17).Interior.Color = 5296274
        ActiveCell.Resize(1, 17).Interior.Color = 5296274

    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True

    For Each Cell In Range("I2:I1000")

    If UCase(Cell.Value) Like "*HIGH*" Then
    Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
    Cell.Font.Bold = True
    End If
    If UCase(Cell.Value) Like "*MEDIUM*" Then Cell.Font.Bold = True
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Range("C2:C1000")

    If UCase(Cell.Value) Like "*RISK*" Then
    Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
    Cell.Font.Bold = True
    End If
    Next Cell

    [A7:A1000].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete


    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Stack overflow is for SPECIFIC question about code.  We're happy to help, but we're not your employees, and it's not our job to read through and improve large chunks of your code.

Comment: Rather than formatting a worksheet which has data, would it be possible to add the data to a formatted template? Then you could essentially copy and paste values and retain the formatting of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is forcing Excel to search through every cell in a sheet, forcing Excel to look in over 17,000,000,000 cells for version 2007 or greater.  Rather than Cells.Find, only search in a specific column for the phrase "Implementation Issue: Issue #".  For example, if the phrase you are searching for is in Column A, use something like

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))

Rng.Find(What:="Implementation Issue: Issue #", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

You might want to reset your Rng variable after you delete a row so Excel looks in even fewer cells after each iteration.

Also, I always add the following to my sub modules (you already have one).  The first one prevents Excel from pushing any screen updates until the macro is finished (this is the biggest saver of time during execution).  The second one turns off all automatic calculations during the macro, which saves a huge amount of time if you have any VLOOKUPS or other array-like formulas.  The last one turns off simple displays such as "Are you sure you want to save this workbooks?" which can cause problems for long running macros where you might step away from your computer.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

And then add them back to normal at the end (chances are that most people want automatic calculations and if they know about manual calculations, then they should know how to set them back to manual).

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

A final piece of advice would be to replace your GoTo function with something like below.  GoTo messages are difficult to debug, break the flow of code, and are generally bad practices to use where it can be avoided (and it can be avoided here).

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Number = 0
'*****DO YOUR CODE WHICH MIGHT RETURN AN ERROR*****
Rng.Find(blah_blah_blah).Activate
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'No Error Occurred
Else
    Debug.Print "An error occurred: " & Err.Number 
End
```

### EDIT 1

Fixed the first code snippet to compile correctly.

Comment: I am trying to setup the Dim Range and I get the error when using your code above. Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. How to I fix that?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

Michael's suggestions are excellent. Here are a few more:

You should try to avoid ***selections*** when coding Excel VBA macros.

Selections are for human users: You select something with the mouse or keyboard, then you perform some operation on the selection.

VBA code should generally operate directly on ***ranges*** without selecting or activating them. The code will be easier to read, and faster. Try rewriting your code without ever using the keywords Select, Selection, Activate, ActiveCell.

It looks like your loops run 1000 times, even after Cells.Find stops finding anything. Use a While (or Until) loop instead. You should also use .FindNext instead of doing a fresh .Find every time.

In this code:

```
For Each Cell In Range("I2:I1000")
    If UCase(Cell.Value) Like "*HIGH*" Then
```

you can actually use a Find instead of using `Like "*HIGH*"` because Find will search for substrings by default, and is case-insensitive by default.

Your code runs in several separate phases. Try doing timings on each phase to see where you need to optimize.  Make liberal use of Debug.Print, and position your windows so that the Debug window remains visible while the macro is executing.

With a rewrite, your macro should run in under 5 seconds!